# A subset A of a group G cannot be a left coset of two distinct subgroups of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If it is so then there will be h and k in G and H and K(distinct) subgroups of G such that A=hH=kK. Now,  |H|=|hH|=|kK|=|K|, If i am able to show that either H is contained in K or K is contained in H, help how to show last thing.

Answer (score 2):

If $hH=kK$ and $e$ denotes the identity then $e\in H=h^{-1}kK$.

This implies that $h^{-1}kK=K$ because a coset of a subgroup that contains the indentity must be the subgroup itself.

So we end up with $H=K$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=xH$, with $H$ a subgroup of $G$, then $H=\{b^{-1}a:a,b\in A\}$.
So the coset $A$ determines the subgroup $H$.

Answer (score 0):

> A=hH=kK

Correct - and, therefore, $H = h^{-1}kK$. But $H$ is a group, so must contain the identity element $e$. So, as $e\in h^{-1}kK$, it's easy to see that $K$ must contain the element $k^{-1}h$. But now $K$ is a group too, so it's closed under inverses, and so it contains $(k^{-1}h)^{-1} = h^{-1} k$. Hence $h^{-1}kK$ is just $K$.